# How to assign an OnClickListener for elements created through the run time?

Tags: android, dynamic, onclick, onclicklistener

My android app requires me to create some LinearLayouts according to data i got through the run time, so i don't know it's number and I have to put it into a for loop to create it, and as a result the name assigned to the layouts or the elements inside it will be overridden with each iterate through the for loop, and that's **my code**:

```
        List<LinearLayout> inner_ver = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size_from_run_time ; i++){
            LinearLayout temp_inner_ver = new LinearLayout(this);
            temp_inner_ver.setLayoutParams(temp_lay);
            temp_inner_ver.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            temp_inner_ver.setWeightSum(2);
            temp_inner_ver.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
            inner_ver.add(temp_inner_ver);
        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j < inner_ver.size() ; j++){
            LinearLayout icon1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            inner_ver.get(j).addView(icon1);

            icon1.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);
            icon1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ac_overlay);
            icon1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            icon1.setTag(NORMAL);

            // icon1
            TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
            icon1.addView(text1);
            text1.setLayoutParams(text_name);
            text1.setText("something");
            text1.setTextSize(12);
            text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            ImageButton rgp1 = new ImageButton(this);
            icon1.addView(rgp1);
            rgp1.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
            rgp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.grp);
            rgp1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            Button rgp_value1 = new Button(this);
            icon1.addView(rgp_value1);
            rgp_value1.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
            rgp_value1.setText("something");
            rgp_value1.setTextSize(12);
            rgp_value1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            rgp_value1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            ImageButton cool1 = new ImageButton(this);
            icon1.addView(cool1);
            cool1.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
            cool1.setImageResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            cool1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            TextView cool_value1 = new TextView(this);
            icon1.addView(cool_value1);
            cool_value1.setLayoutParams(text_cool);
            cool_value1.setText("something");
            cool_value1.setTextSize(12);

            ver_rooms.addView(inner_ver.get(j)); // ver_rooms is a LinearLayout defined through the xml

        }
```

So, what if i want to add an `OnClickListener` for the created items (e.g `rgb1`, `rgb_value1`, `cool1`), as I may have like **10** of `inner_ver` and all of them for sure contains all of these elements with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably create an array or ArrayList of 10 inner_ver.Here I have assumed, innerVerList is an Array that holds List of LinearLayout.

```
   for (LinearLayout l: list){
       for(int i=0; i<l.getChildCount(); ++i){
            l.getChildAt(i).addOnClickListner(/*name of onClick listener here*/ );
       }
    }
```

But I still don't get when will you need so many LinearLayouts. Though I hope it helps!
Happy coding!

Comment: I don't know why but when trying that it gives me a syntax error i don't get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type LinearLayout to List<LinearLayout>` and as you know `inner_ver` is a list of layouts not just a layout

Comment: it worked, just change `addOnClickListener` to `setOnClickListener`